# How to specify sensitive environment variables with ECS CLI and ECS tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

In the `environment:` section of `docker-compose` docs for AWS CLI ([cmd-ecs-cli-compose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html)), the following is stated:

> Important
>
> We do not recommend using plaintext environment variables for sensitive > information, such as credential data.

What is the recommended way of storing sensitive information, like passwords, with docker-compose and ECS task definitions? Why is plain text not recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain text is not recommended for environment variables because well docker is not a security container and environment variables are readable to all processes that have access to the top level Docker namespace. So if someone has access to `/proc` on your EC2 instance, they can read the secrets by querying the process running inside the container.

I recommend either encrypting them with KMS or storing them in Parameter Store or DynamoDB and downloading on startup.